# EmberJs: RESTAdapter could not get json file, showing error 404 (not found)

Tags: javascript, json, rest, ember.js, adapter

My following Ember App works well for `FIXTUREAdapter`. Now I am trying to use `RESTAdapter` instead of `FIXTURE`. But now console displaying **Error:**

`GET http://localhost/myApp/note.json/notes 404 (Not Found)`.

`Error while loading route: undefined`

I'm using **XAMPP**.

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({
    LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'myApp/note.json'
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('notes');
  this.route('note', { path: 'note/:note_id' });
});

App.NotesRoute = Ember.Route.extend ({
 model: function() {
    return this.store.findAll('note');
 }
});

App.NoteRoute = Ember.Route.extend ({
 model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('note', params.note_id);
 }
});

App.Note = DS.Model.extend ({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  body: DS.attr('string')
});
```

note.json:

```
{
  "notes": [ 
      {
       id: 1,
       title: 'hello world', 
       body: 'ciao ciao'
      }, 
      { 
       id: 2, 
       title: 'javascript frameworks',
       body: 'Backbone.js, Ember.js'
      },
      {
       id: 3,
       title: 'Find a job in Berlin',
       body: 'Monster'
      }
   ]
}
```

index.html handlebars template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
  {{partial 'navbar'}} 
  {{outlet}}
</script>

<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='_navbar'>
 {{#link-to 'index'}}Home{{/link-to}}
 {{#link-to 'notes'}}Notes{{/link-to}}
</script>

<script type='text/x-handlebars' data-template-name='index'>
 <h1>Index page!</h1>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="notes">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
      {{#each}}
        <li class="list-group-item">
          {{#link-to 'note' this}} {{title}} {{/link-to}}
        </li>
      {{else}}
        <li>No data!</li>
      {{/each}}
   </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="note">
 <p>{{title}}</p>
 <p>{{body}}</p>
</script>
```

Comment: Which endpoint returns the json results `http://localhost/myApp/note.json/notes` or `http://localhost/myApp/note.json`?

Comment: @kingpin2k I can view the JSON file in `http://localhost/myApp/note.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to the docs](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#toc_customization), `namespace` is a prefix.

You probably want this instead:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'myApp'
});
```

As you're using PHP, rename your `notes.json` to `notes.php`, and just make sure the correct headers are set when responding:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json");
?>

// Add your json data here:
{
  "notes": [
  {id: 1, ...},
 ]
}
```

If you're not using any PHP framework, you need to rewrite the url yourself (if you use a framework, it will most likely take care of the url rewriting for you).

Since you're using Apache, just add an .htaccess file to the same directory as the one containing your notes.php file, and add the following rewrite rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteRule ^notes$ notes.php
</IfModule>
```

This rewrite rule will enable you to access `http://localhost/myApp/notes` (without the `.php` file extension).

You also need to make sure you use valid JSON, i.e. everything should be quoted:

```
{
    "notes": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "title": "helloworld",
            "body": "ciaociao"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "title": "javascriptframeworks",
            "body": "Backbone.js, Ember.js"
        },
        {
            "id": "3",
            "title": "FindajobinBerlin",
            "body": "Monster"
        }
    ]
}
```

You should rather set up your routes like this:

```
this.resource("notes", function() {
    this.route("view", {
        path: "/:note_id"
    });
});
```

Then you need to rename your `"note"` template to `"notes/view"`, like this: 
`<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="notes/view">`

And rewrite your `"notes"`template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="notes">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
      {{#each note in model}}
        <li class="list-group-item">
          {{#link-to 'notes.view' note}} {{note.title}} {{/link-to}}
        </li>
      {{else}}
        <li>No data!</li>
      {{/each}}
   </ul>
   {{outlet}}
</script>
```

Comment: Seems to be the convention. Can you rename your endpoint to just `notes`, without the file extension? The `.json` shouldn't be necessary as long the server responds with a `Content-Type` header of `application/json`.

Comment: Should I put `headers` for json inside `RESTAdapter`? I've found smthing like this here http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/passing-header-information-to-rest-get-request-using-restadapter/4220

Comment: No, that is for sending headers TO the server. I edited my reply above. What server side language do you use? (If you're just serving a static `.json` file, why are you using the REST adapter?)

Comment: I am using PHP. I've written this json file data manually without using PHP  to test that if RESTAdapter can get data from this file. But I will use PHP to provide dynamic list of notes to the JSON file from a database. Won't RESTAdapter work without writing json file using PHP?

Comment: Good, then you should be able `GET` the data from `http://localhost/myApp/notes` , and set the correct headers.
`header('Content-Type: application/json');`

Comment: I've edited my answer somewhat as I didn't pay attention to the fact that you were using XAMPP until now, sorry my bad :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57160/discussion-between-hasib-mahmud-and-stefanb).

Comment: wow great it works, to understand how to make RESTAdapter work in Ember, something like this answer should be in Ember Doc.